# Rails ActiveRecord - field vallidation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am new to rails and in my models am doing some field validation and i need some help

```
  has_many :stats
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { minimum: 2 }
  validates :age, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, format: { with: ???????????????
    message: "must begin with abc_ and have numbers after" }
```

I am stuck trying to validate title to be in the format abc_8943578945794

Is this where I should really create a method to validate?

Thanks, Nigel.

Comment: You're gonna need a regular expression there. If so, you should add more examples of the input you might be working with. Also, you might want to add some db constraints, and for that is better to know what RDMBS (if any) you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're looking for a regular expression to match the title, try this:

`with: /^[a-z]+_[0-9]+$/`

Comment: Thank you Fernando

Answer (score 1):

Fernando Almeida's anwers is right, you need a regex to match the expected value, but for the format that "OP" have passed (abc_8943578945794), this seems more suitable:

`/^[a-z]{3}_[0-9]{13}$/`

The only thing that I'm doing more than his, is setting the number of digits (3) and characters (13) that the string should have.

Comment: Really appreciate this explanation. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following regexp:

```
with: /\Aabc_\d+\z/
```

Explanation:

```
\A    # beginning of the string
abc_  # string prefix you are looking for
\d+   # one or more digits
\z    # end of the string
```

Comment: That's great, thanks and thank you for breakdown of explanation.